# Escaping colons in JQuery Templates

Tags: jquery, escaping, jquery-templates

I have the following JQuery Template

```
<script id="SearchResultsTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
{{each Hits}}
Page ${PAGENUMBER} - ${autn:summary} 
{{/each}}
</script>'
```

I can pull the PAGENUMBER tag out of the JSON but the template is not compiled correctly when i try and use autn:summary

How can I escape it?

I have tried \: and \\: and \3A but it complains about invalid characters.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do I understand correctly that your data or a sub part of your data has a colon in the key?  Then, if your data looks like this:

```
{
  "a:1": 1,
  "sub": [{
    "b:1": 'x'
  },{
    "b:1": 'y'
  }]
}
```

use the following in your template

```
${$data['a:1']}
{{each(i,s) sub}}
    ${s['b:1']}
{{/each}}
```

jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/brettwp/p9WUN/

Comment: yeps, that's correct, in the end i gave up and just renamed the source data as it was generated by a web-service i had written.. bit hacky but time was tight...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `\\` (double backslash)?

for selectors you have to do that. Maybe it's the same in your case. Look [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: sorry, i didn't escape the double escape in my post :D